# expected string or bytes-like object error while downloading data from s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```py
    import os
    import sys
    import boto3
    import argparse

    awsParams = {
    "bucket_name": "<bucket_name>",
    "region_name": "<region_name>"}
     
    def get_s3_client():
    s3Client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='<access_key>', aws_secret_access_key='<secret_access_key>')

    return s3Client

    def download_from_s3(srcDir, dstDir):
    try:
        bucketName = awsParams['bucket_name'] #s3 bucket name
        
        s3Client = get_s3_client()
        s3Obj = get_s3_object()
        bucket = s3Obj.Bucket(bucketName)

        keys = []
        dirs = []
        next_token = ''

        base_kwargs = {
            'Bucket':bucket,
            'srcDir':srcDir,
        }
        
        while next_token is not None:
            kwargs = base_kwargs.copy()
            if next_token != '':
                kwargs.update({'ContinuationToken': next_token})
            results = s3Client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
            contents = results.get('Contents')
            for i in contents:
                k = i.get('Key')
                if k[-1] != '/':
                    keys.append(k)
                else:
                    dirs.append(k)
            next_token = results.get('NextContinuationToken')
            next_token = k.get('NextContinuationToken')
        for d in dirs:
            dest_pathname = os.path.join(dst, d)
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
        for k in keys:
            dest_pathname = os.path.join(dst, k)
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_pathname))
            s3Client.download_file(bucket, k, dest_pathname)
    except Exception as e:
        raise
}
```

I want to download a folder from my s3 bucket. When I run this code, I get the following error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "icr/test_aws_transfer_util.py", line 117, in <module>
    download_from_s3(srcDir=src, dstDir=dst)

  File "icr/test_aws_transfer_util.py", line 70, in download_from_s3
    results = s3Client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 691, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 737, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params = self._emit_api_params(

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 766, in _emit_api_params
    self.meta.events.emit(

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 357, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)

  File "/home/madhura/OCR/icr-microservice/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 238, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here and what should I change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
bucket = s3Obj.Bucket(bucketName)
```

is creating an **object** of type `<class 'boto3.resources.factory.s3.Bucket'>`.

Then, these lines:

```json
        base_kwargs = {
            'Bucket':bucket,
            'srcDir':srcDir,
        }
```

are creating a dictionary with `base_kwargs['Bucket']` equal to the above object.

Then this line:

```
results = s3Client.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
```

is using those `kwargs`, and the error is:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

The `list_objects_v2()` function is expecting `Bucket` to be a string, not a 'Bucket object'.

You do not require this code:

```
bucket = s3Obj.Bucket(bucketName)
```

Instead, just use the bucket name as a string.

Comment: So I removed that line, and replaced "bucket" with "bucketName"  But still getting an error :- 
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "srcDir", must be one of: Bucket, Delimiter, EncodingType, MaxKeys, Prefix, ContinuationToken, FetchOwner, StartAfter, RequestPayer, ExpectedBucketOwner

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Did you write the code you have shown? If so, hopefully you wold know why that parameter is being provided (because I don't!). Given that its name probably means "source directory", then the equivalent in the `list_objects_v2()` command would be `Prefix`. So, the kwargs dictionary should be changed to `'Prefix': srcdir` -- but that's just an assumption.